# Google Coral Edge TPU: RuntimeError

Tags: installation

i just installed the new Google Edge TPU using exactly this tutorial [Google TPU USB accelerator](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/accelerator/get-started/)

Here some information about my system:

```
uname -a 
Linux user-desktop 4.15.0-47-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 15 16:06:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My python installation:

```
python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

So know if i'm trying to run some of the demo scripts, the following happens:

**(Demo1)**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/demo$ python3 object_detection.py --model ~/Downloads/mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --input ~/Downloads/face.jpg --output ~/detection_results.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "object_detection.py", line 75, in main
    engine = DetectionEngine(args.model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 55, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors.
```

**(Demo2)**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/demo$ python3 classify_image.py --model ~/Downloads/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite --label ~/Downloads/inat_bird_labels.txt --image ~/Downloads/parrot.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_image.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "classify_image.py", line 58, in main
    engine = ClassificationEngine(args.model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/classification/engine.py", line 38, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors.
```

I exactly followed the install instructions.
Some extra note: I installed the **Intel mediaSDK** before. During install the following output was generated:

```
~/edgetpu_api$ bash ./install.sh 
Recognized as Linux on x86_64.
Warning: During normal operation, the Edge TPU Accelerator may heat up, depending
on the computation workloads and operating frequency. Touching the metal part of the
device after it has been operating for an extended period of time may lead to discomfort
and/or skin burns. As such, when running at the default operating frequency, the device is
intended to safely operate at an ambient temperature of 35C or less. Or when running at
the maximum operating frequency, it should be operated at an ambient temperature of
25C or less.

Google does not accept any responsibility for any loss or damage if the device is operated
outside of the recommended ambient temperature range.
.............................................................
Would you like to enable the maximum operating frequency? Y/N
N
Using default operating frequency.
Installing library dependencies...
[sudo] password for example_user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcc1 is already the newest version (1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1).
libunwind8 is already the newest version (1.1-4.1).
libusb-1.0-0 is already the newest version (2:1.0.20-1).
python3-numpy is already the newest version (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1).
python3-pil is already the newest version (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1).
libc++1 is already the newest version (3.7.0-1ubuntu0.1).
libc++abi1 is already the newest version (3.7.0-1ubuntu0.1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-42 linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-43 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-45 linux-headers-4.15.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-42-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-45-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 215 not upgraded.
Done.
Installing device rule file [/etc/udev/rules.d/99-edgetpu-accelerator.rules]...
File already exists. Replacing it...
Done.
Installing Edge TPU runtime library [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedgetpu.so.1.0]...
File already exists. Replacing it...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/common/mdf/lib64/igfxcmrt64.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-drm.so.2 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva.so.2 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-glx.so.2 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfx.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-x11.so.2 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libigdgmm.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Done.
Installing Edge TPU Python API...
The directory '/home/example_user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/example_user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Done.
```

May someone can help me? I don't know whats going wrong!

Kind regards,
Timo

**EDIT:**
I additionally noticed that the TPU has to be unplugged and plugged, before i can restart the demo script

```
sudo python3 object_detection.py --model ~/Downloads/mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --input ~/Downloads/face.jpg --output ~/detection_results.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "object_detection.py", line 75, in main
    engine = DetectionEngine(args.model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 55, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: No Edge TPU device detected!
```

EDIT:

I tested it on two Ubuntu 16.04 systems. On both of them "OpenVINO" and "MediaSDK" by Intel is installed before installing the EdgeTPU. Both of them raise these "*symbolic link" Issues. and on both of them the stick does not work...

EDIT:
I tested the install guide on a blank ubuntu 16.04 system and it works. So I think it is caused by OpenVINO or MediaSDK by Intel. But even after uninstalling OpenVINO and MediaSDK it does not work...

Edit:
I wrote a little code snippet in python

```
from edgetpu.basic.edgetpu_utils import ListEdgeTpuPaths, EDGE_TPU_STATE_ASSIGNED, EDGE_TPU_STATE_NONE, EDGE_TPU_STATE_UNASSIGNED

print("Assigned: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_ASSIGNED))
print("Unassigned: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_UNASSIGNED))
print("None: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_NONE))
```

After multiply times the result stays at:

```
Assigned:  ()
Unassigned:  ('/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3.4',)
None:  ('/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3.4',)
```

While running

```
basic_engine = edgetpu.basic.basic_engine.BasicEngine(
    %%%the_demo_network_path%%%
)
```

it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/corvitac/3TB_Data_Storage/corvitac-Server/corvitac_code/python_workspace/utilities/MachineLearning/EdgeTPU/demotest.py", line 10, in <module>
    "/home/corvitac/Downloads/mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 300, in __init__
    this = _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.new_BasicEngine(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors.
```

and if I retry

```
print("Assigned: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_ASSIGNED))
print("Unassigned: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_UNASSIGNED))
print("None: ", ListEdgeTpuPaths(state=EDGE_TPU_STATE_NONE))
```

the result is

```
Assigned:  ()
Unassigned:  ()
None:  ()
```

Comment: Did you try to run the command using "sudo" ?

Comment: Yes, i used sudo and sudo -H

Comment: I don't see these logs "* is not a symbolic link" in normal installation. Can you try to install again with maximum frequency enabled ?

Comment: "* is not a symbolic link"  is caused by some missing symbolic links in "sudo ldconfig". I fixed the links, but after that it even does not allocate the tensors. I reinstalled it with maximum frequency -> The same problem

Comment: Can you make sure that your user is part of "plugdev" group ?

Comment: Yes, i'm in it!

Comment: I assume you are not using working on a virtual box or VMWare ?

Comment: No, not using VM or vb!

Answer (score 2):

it's really weird but I solved my problem. As you can see in my description, the only similarity between my two test systems is Intel OpenVINO/MediaSDK. But OpenVINO/MediaSDK dind't cause the issue! After days of testing I noticed, that plugging the stick to an other USB-Controller (on the back, side of my system) solved the issue... The same on my other Device.

**The problem is the USB controller! I don't know why the Coral TPU is in conflict with some of them.**

Kind regards,

Timo

Answer (score 1):

What is the output of `lsusb`? You will need to see something like this:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 18d1:9302 Google Inc.
```

If you do not see that, but see something with "Global Unichip Corp", then unplug/replug or reboot may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the first error "RuntimeError: Failed to allocate tensors" when I run the classify_image in coral dev board. The problem I find is the version of edgetpu_compiler. And I solve it via recompiler the model using "edgetpu_compiler --min_runtime_version 10 your_model.tflite".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, just following their Get Started page, which is basically the AI version of “Hello World”.  With so few steps involved it’s pretty hard to mess up :) I ended up getting a Raspberry Pi B+ just to see if the result would be the same or different and the Get Started instructions worked great on that device.

I know it’s not the answer you’re hoping for, but I’ll bet there’s some recent regression in the software tools for x86 that the coral relies on.